# Nashorn: Import Java object in Typescript

Tags: java, javascript, typescript, nashorn

I need to know if it's possible to import a Java object (specifically, an enum class) in a Typescript script.

I've googled but haven't found anything.

The ErrorCodeAuthority is for having custom, standardized errors thrown from our service for each known error with set messages (some parameterized, some not), http status codes, etc defined in one place.

In our javascript code we have

```
var JavaErrorCodeAuthority = Java.type("com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority");
```

Is it possible to do the same in Typescript?

I've declared the following:

```
declare module Java {
    export enum ErrorCodeAuthority {
        ENTITY_NOT_FOUND,
        HTTP_VERB_NOT_SUPPORTED,
        BAD_REQUEST,
        //...
    }
    export function type(arg: "com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority"): ErrorCodeAuthority;
    export function type(arg: string): any;
}
var JavaErrorCodeAuthority = Java.type("com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority");
```

and I'm attempting to use the new type as follows:

```
export class HttpFailResult extends HttpResult {
    constructor(public errorCode : Java.ErrorCodeAuthority, public userParams? : UserParam[]) {
        super(errorCode.httpStatus.value(), errorCode.toString());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when I try to use grunt to compile to js:

```
error TS2339: Property 'httpStatus' does not exist on type 'ErrorCodeAuthority'.
```

(For reference, the super `HttpResult` is an object that contains a `number` `http code and a` string`body.  HttpStatus, in the Java enum, is of type`org.springframework.http.HttpStatus`).

I tried removing the `export function type(arg: "com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority"): ErrorCodeAuthority;` line but that didn't change the exception.

We're running all of this inside a nashorn container if that makes a difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to do the same in Typescript?

Yes. With [tyrian](https://github.com/wizawu/tyrian), you can just write

```
let JavaErrorCodeAuthority = com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority
```

And there will be auto-completion on each level of packages.

Comment: Belated and this is no longer even a requirement for us as we (thankfully) abandoned running a mixed java/javascript server, but thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you already did this in JavaScript you can use the code by creating a definition file for it and port it to TypeScript.
An example might be like this:

```
declare module Java {
    export enum ErrorCodeAuthority {
        item1,
        item2
    }
    export function type(arg: "com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority"): ErrorCodeAuthority;
    export function type(arg: string): any;
}
var JavaErrorCodeAuthority = Java.type("com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority");
```

The enum and the first type function with the "com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority" is optional but it gives you better typeinfo when passed in that particular string. Note the declare module part doesn't generate any code and you can add it to a `.ts` or `.d.ts` file. More info about creating a definition file can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing%20Definition%20Files

### EDIT

after the info from the comments I hope this code below will better suite your need.
This has the downside that it isn't usable in a switch statement but in this case I think it is better to see the java enum as a module (or class was possible to). This might not be 100% correctly modelled but hopefully it gives you some extra idea's. Just a small side note, I find your case very interesting and challenging!

```
declare module Java {
    interface ErrorCodeValue {
       toString(): string;
       value(): number;
    }
    module ErrorCodeAuthority {
        var ENTITY_NOT_FOUND: IErrorCodeAuthority;
        var HTTP_VERB_NOT_SUPPORTED: IErrorCodeAuthority;
        var BAD_REQUEST: IErrorCodeAuthority;
    } 
    interface IErrorCodeAuthority {
        httpStatus: ErrorCodeValue;
    }
    export function type(arg: "com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority"): typeof ErrorCodeAuthority;
    export function type(arg: string): any;
}
export class HttpResult {
    constructor(code: number, description: string) {        
    }
}
export class HttpFailResult extends HttpResult {
    constructor(public errorCode: Java.IErrorCodeAuthority, public userParams? :any[]) {
        super(errorCode.httpStatus.value(), errorCode.toString());
    }
}
var JavaErrorCodeAuthority = Java.type("com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority");
new HttpFailResult(JavaErrorCodeAuthority.BAD_REQUEST, null);
```

Comment: Will this allow me to reference, say, `ErrorCodeAuthority.ITEM_NOT_FOUND.customErrorMessage`? (using the Java enhanced enum capabilities)

Comment: If you remove `export function type(arg: "com.domain.ErrorCodeAuthority"): ErrorCodeAuthority` and use it as any, yes then it is possible. I don't think it is possible with typechecking because I don't think it is possible to combine ITEM_NOT_FOUND and ITEM_NOT_FOUND.httpStatus in TypeScript

Comment: Ok thank you.  I'll try this when I get back to the office in the morning

Comment: Ok so I've attempted your solution as above and it's gotten me somewhere, but I'm still stuck on the enhanced enum bit.  I added some additional details to the question based on your answer, mind taking a look?

Comment: Is it a requirement that it can be used in a switch?  (ErrorCodeAuthority.ENTITY_NOT_FOUND) because that is making it pretty hard with the java enum style in TypeScript.

Comment: Use in a switch is not required.  The idea was to have a list of "valid" error messages with pre-defined associated http status codes, internal error codes, and user-displayable error messages

Comment: Edited my answer with the stuff from your comments and your edited answer. Hopefully it helps you fixing your problem :)

Comment: Thanks! That looks promising.  I've been called to another project for the time being so I will have to come back to this but I appreciate the help!